# Why do relative imports in __init__.py also bind the module to its name?

Tags: python, python-import

Suppose I have the following directory structure:

`x/a.py`

with contents:

```
__all__ = ['x']
x = 2
```

and
`x/__init__.py`
with contents

```
from .a import x
print(a)
```

Now, `import x` prints

`<module 'x.a' from '/home/neil/src/cmm/x/a.py'>`

Why did `a` get bound?  I thought I was only importing and therefore binding `x`.  I can understand if I did `import a`, but why should a relative import import anything but what was requested?

This doesn't seem to happen for relative imports in other files.  Why is `__init__` special?

This is a problem because `mypy` complains all over the place with errors like

```
session/__init__.py:12: error: Name 'extrema' already defined (by an import)
```

Comment: Since you imported from `.a`, `a` gets created and put on “`.`”. mypy is reporting an accurate problem. Consider putting less stuff in `__init__.py`.

Comment: @Ry-  I can see that that is happening, but my question is why is this good design?  Where does this come in handy?

Comment: @Ry- Also, why does this happen only in `__init__.py`?  Finally, I don't know what you mean by this being a problem.  This is the accepted way to collect many objects in a package.

Comment: mypy is reporting an accurate problem assuming you redefined things that were already defined. Are you doing `import extrema` or something to try to reexport it? You don’t need to. And sorry, I probably wasn’t clear – importing `x.a` *anywhere* creates `a` and places it on `x`. It’s just that in this case `x` and the module importing `x.a` are the same module.

Comment: Loading `x.a` anywhere in the program also binds the `x.a` attribute so `x.a.whatever()` works properly. There's definitely a duplicate somewhere around here.

Comment: Maybe a real-world library example would help. In the REPL, try `import urllib`, then `urllib.parse`, then `from urllib.parse import urlparse`, then `urllib.parse` again.

Comment: @Ry- If I rename `__init__.py` to `b.py`, and then `import x.b`, it does not bind `a`.

Comment: @Ry- There is no duplicate.  The problem is that inside the `extrema` package, I have an `extrema` module?

Comment: I’m not the one who marked it as a duplicate, but it *is* a duplicate, so read that. What’s on line 12 of the code that gives you a mypy error?

Comment: @Ry- `from .extrema import *`, and the package `extrema` contains an init file that has the same line to import from its module of the same name.